# Reverse Order of String

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to reverse the order of string in one column in SQL Server.

Example:

```
"Smith,John" expected to "John Smith".
"Depp,Johnny" expected to "Johnny Depp".
```

Any idea how can I split it by comma, then concat that separated by space?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Be sure to check your data, for example, if any of the name fields does not have a common, the code below will fail.     Run a query to identify any name columns that do not contain a comma, and manually fix those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend "reconstruction":

```
select concat(stuff(str, 1, charindex(',', str), ''), ' ',
              left(str, chardindex(',', str) - 1)
             ) as reversed_names
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as the following

```
SELECT S, CONCAT(
                 REPLACE(S, LEFT(S, CHARINDEX(',', S)), ''), ' ', 
                 LEFT(S, CHARINDEX(',', S)-1)
                )
FROM (VALUES('Smith,John'), ('Depp,Johnny')) T(S)
```

Comment: different and nice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to decompose it & recompose :

```
select concat(substring(col, charindex(',', col)+1, len(col)), ' ',
              left(col, charindex(',', col)-1)
             )
```